# The theory of operation of NPN BJT

Tags: transistors, bjt

In NPN BJT transistor, I know that the current is pulled by the reverse voltage in the NP junction at the collector side

Why can't the current take the route that I have drawn in the picture (the green one?) Why can't the voltage of the VBE pull all the charges and make it move like the green arrow?

To summarize, my question is: Why do the charges run towards the collector side instead of being pulled by the VBE voltage?  Why can't the VBE pull them towards it?

[image]

This image is taken from A. Sedra & K. Smith *Microelectronic Circuits*, Oxford University Press, 8th ed. 2019.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can current flow through the reverse biased base-collector junction (N-P junction) in a BJT with a forward biased base-emitter junction?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125270/why-can-current-flow-through-the-reverse-biased-base-collector-junction-n-p-jun)

Comment: You will need a course on semiconductor physics and really a course on quantum mechanics to understand. The descriptions given in all intro semiconductor device books all have massive logical flaws.

Comment: Is your green arrow supposed to represent electron flow or (conventional) current?

Comment: @thephoton, the electron flow

Comment: @Mans There's a little more to see from [Jacob Millman, 1979, **Microelectronics: Digital and Analog Circuits and Systems**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brEJZ.jpg). It's a beginning text on semiconductor physics and pretty easy to read. May want to consider any of the beginning `microelectronic` texts dealing with semiconductors. Charges making up currents will follow the local gradient, consistent with thermal jostling. They don't 'choose to go' anywhere.

Comment: @Mans - You asked the same question at Physics.SE. That post has now been migrated back to here and I've merged it into this one. Please do *not* post the same question on multiple SE sites - choose one site and stick with it. More etiquette info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You do have some current flow that way - iB2 in the diagram - from electrons that recombine in the base. This is bad from the standpoint of amplification since it requires a larger input signal to provide the same output signal. To minimize this, the base is made as thin as possible so that minority carriers entering the base diffuse quickly towards the collector-base depletion region where they encounter the electric field set by the collector-base bias and drift out of the p-type region.

Comment: So your answer is that, due to making the base very thin the electrons diffuses very quickly so that the VBE don't have the time to pull them towards it , is what I'm saying correct?

Comment: I think you might be seeing the connection on the side of the base area as drawn and thinking that the terminal is pulling them to the side (down, in your diagram). This is really just a convenient way to show the base connection, the charge movement into or out of the base terminal happens when a minority carrier recombines anywhere in the base area.  Also, BJTs are not physically constructed like the drawing. They're usually a succession of nested wells or something similar.

Comment: @Mans, typically \$V_{CB}\$ is greater than \$V_{BE}\$. This becomes similar to "why doesn't **all** the current flow through the path of least resistance?" It flows through all paths depending on the voltages across them and the nature of device in the path. The CB junction is more complicated than a resistor, but it will pass current when \$V_{CB}\$ and \$V_{BE}\$ are both positive...the fact that it depends on both of these voltages and not just the one directly across the CB junction is what makes the transistor more interesting than a resistor.

Comment: @vir, isn't the VBE apply an electric Field that pulls the electrons form the conduction band towards it?

Comment: Forward-biasing the base-emitter junction unbalances the depletion region equilibrium by reducing drift, which allows minority carriers to enter the base.

Comment: @vir, Could you provide any reference that explains how it works, because I still didn't understand it's operation

Comment: Physics of Semiconductor Devices, S. M. Sze, Yiming Li, e al.

Answer (score 1):

The direction of current is opposite to the direction of flow of electrons because of a convention that was established before the discovery of electrons as the charge carriers in conductors.

The electron flow in an NPN BJT transistor is the result of the forward biasing of the base-emitter junction, which allows the majority charge carriers (electrons) to move from the emitter to the base region. The base region acts as a control input that determines whether the transistor is turned on or off. When the base voltage is higher than the emitter voltage, a small amount of electrons from the emitter diffuse into the base and recombine with holes (positive charge carriers) in the base. This creates a small current (Ib) that flows into the base terminal. If this current is sufficient to overcome the threshold voltage (Vth) of the transistor, then a larger amount of electrons will flow from the emitter to the collector, creating a larger current (Ic) that flows out of the collector terminal. This current is called collector current and it is proportional to Ib by a factor called beta (β), which is also known as current gain or hfe. The ratio of Ic to Ib is given by:

$$\beta = \frac{I_c}{I_b} = \frac{V_{CC} - V_{BE}}{V_{CC} - V_{th}}$$

where \$V_{CC}\$ is the supply voltage, \$V_{BE}\$ is the base-emitter voltage drop, and \$V_{th}\$ is the threshold voltage.

The NPN BJT transistor can be used for amplifying or switching signals, depending on how it is biased and connected. For example, in a common emitter configuration, where both emitter and collector are connected to ground, an external resistor (Rb) can be used to limit Ib and provide feedback for adjusting β.

Since the flow of electrons can't be in opposite direction 'green arrow', you can't get a current in the way specified.

A great YouTube video to clear fundamentals regarding BJT : [watch it!](https://youtu.be/7ukDKVHnac4?feature=shared)

Comment: I meant why can't the electrons take the green route ? ,why it continues to the collector side ? ,  why  the VBE voltage can't pull the electrons towards it rather than flowing into the collector side ?

Comment: It's mainly due to less hole density in base region, which makes electrons move towards collector side having more holes,btw there is video link now added into answer do check it it's great explanation, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can, you essentially have a diode at that point. Depending on the direction it will be blocking or let current through. The problem is BJT's make poor diodes.

https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/semiconductor/knowledge/faq/mosfet_common/is-it-ok-to-use-a-transistor-as-a-diode.html